# svelte - multiple components with their own isolated interactions and values

Tags: javascript, svelte-3, svelte-component

I created a toggle button components so that i can use it in various places in project:

```
<style>
  .butt{
    background:blue;
  }
  .butt.active{
    background:lightblue;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function toggle(e){
    console.log('toggle')
    console.log(e.target.id)
    let el = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
    el.classList.toggle("active")
  }
</script>

<div
on:click={toggle}
class="butt"
id="abc"
>sample button</div>
```

then I add it to my `app.svelte`:

```
<script>
  import Togglebutt from "./Togglebutt.svelte"
</script>

{#each [1,2,3] as thing (thing)}
  <Togglebutt />
{/each}
```

I have 2 issues here:

1. for every button click, it only trigger the first button, never the 2 and the 3.
2. the css class `active` is added, but the button never render to the color intended.

How can I resolve these 2 issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is caused by the fact that you would have three buttons that each have an id of `abc` when doing the `document.getElementById(e.target.id)` it will **always** return the first it found. This issue could be resolved by passing an id in as a property so that each of your toggles has an unique id.

The other problem is that Svelte will remove all style declaration that are *not explicitely used* in your markup, the `active` class is nowhere used in your markup so it will be removed.

When using Svelte it is generally not a good idea to manipulate your DOM directly like this and instead rely on that state of your component and Svelte's internal logic to manage this for you.

This means that in your script you will have a variable that tracks the state of your components:

```html
<script>
  export let toggled = false
</script>
```

And you use this state to conditionally add the class to the element

```html
<div class:active={toggled}></div>
```

You could go a step further and use the shorthand for the conditional class which requires the variable and the class to be same name: `<div class:toggled></div>`

This gives us a full component of

```html
<style>
  .butt {
    background:blue;
  }
  .butt.toggled {
    background:lightblue;
  }
</style>

<script>
  export let toggled = false

  function toggle() {
    toggled = !toggled
  }
</script>

<div
  on:click={toggle}
  class="butt"
  class:toggled
>sample button</div>
```